# How to line up dataset in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe which includes channel name, time, values, update interval. It is grouped by ch_name.  Time = when data received, update interval = difference between first received and second received value(this is a telemetry data, where channels updates with specific time rate according to their functions).

So I have update intervals: 1, 4, 10, 20, 30, 60 (secs). I need dataframe where all update intervals equal to 60 secs. 
For example, Channel_X has update interval 1 sec. So I need mean value according to 60 secs data. (I do not need 60 data during 60 secs, I need only 1 mean value for 60 secs) and so on. If update interval equal to 4 secs, I need mean of 15 values for 60 secs. See dataframe output below:

```
ch_name                time  value  interval
167      ADCS.GPS_EPI_-_ECC 2019-09-26 00:00:06  0.001       4.0
442      ADCS.GPS_EPI_-_ECC 2019-09-26 00:00:10  0.001       4.0
548      ADCS.GPS_EPI_-_ECC 2019-09-26 00:00:14  0.001       4.0
752      ADCS.GPS_EPI_-_ECC 2019-09-26 00:00:18  0.001       4.0
916      ADCS.GPS_EPI_-_ECC 2019-09-26 00:00:22  0.001       4.0
...                     ...                 ...    ...       ...
5925943  ADCS.GPS_EPI_-_ECC 2019-09-27 08:59:41  0.001       4.0
5926102  ADCS.GPS_EPI_-_ECC 2019-09-27 08:59:45  0.001       4.0
5926265  ADCS.GPS_EPI_-_ECC 2019-09-27 08:59:49  0.001       4.0
5926432  ADCS.GPS_EPI_-_ECC 2019-09-27 08:59:53  0.001       4.0
5926595  ADCS.GPS_EPI_-_ECC 2019-09-27 08:59:57  0.001       4.0


ch_name                time  value  interval
498      Payload.OBCARM_DCDC_Temp_degC 2019-09-26 00:00:13  5.229      10.0
988      Payload.OBCARM_DCDC_Temp_degC 2019-09-26 00:00:23  5.229      10.0
1324     Payload.OBCARM_DCDC_Temp_degC 2019-09-26 00:00:33  5.229      10.0
1895     Payload.OBCARM_DCDC_Temp_degC 2019-09-26 00:00:43  5.383      10.0
2254     Payload.OBCARM_DCDC_Temp_degC 2019-09-26 00:00:53  5.383      10.0
...                                ...                 ...    ...       ...
5926944  Payload.OBCARM_DCDC_Temp_degC 2019-09-27 09:02:52  6.617      11.0
5926960  Payload.OBCARM_DCDC_Temp_degC 2019-09-27 09:03:02  6.617      10.0
5926979  Payload.OBCARM_DCDC_Temp_degC 2019-09-27 09:03:13  6.617      11.0
5926989  Payload.OBCARM_DCDC_Temp_degC 2019-09-27 09:03:23  6.617      10.0
5927004  Payload.OBCARM_DCDC_Temp_degC 2019-09-27 09:03:34  6.617      11.0




ch_name                time  value  interval
2917     Housekeeping.PDM_0__SW10_Status 2019-09-26 00:01:06    0.0      30.0
4318     Housekeeping.PDM_0__SW10_Status 2019-09-26 00:01:36    0.0      30.0
5713     Housekeeping.PDM_0__SW10_Status 2019-09-26 00:02:06    0.0      30.0
7073     Housekeeping.PDM_0__SW10_Status 2019-09-26 00:02:36    0.0      30.0
8518     Housekeeping.PDM_0__SW10_Status 2019-09-26 00:03:06    0.0      30.0
...                                  ...                 ...    ...       ...
5398900  Housekeeping.PDM_0__SW10_Status 2019-09-27 05:57:36    0.0      30.0
5400155  Housekeeping.PDM_0__SW10_Status 2019-09-27 05:58:06    0.0      30.0
5401490  Housekeeping.PDM_0__SW10_Status 2019-09-27 05:58:36    0.0      30.0
5402885  Housekeeping.PDM_0__SW10_Status 2019-09-27 05:59:06    0.0      30.0
5404257  Housekeeping.PDM_0__SW10_Status 2019-09-27 05:59:36    0.0      30.0
```

Comment: If time starts with 00:00:00 this dataframe has 1440 rows, but when time starts with 00:01:06 it has 1439 rows. How can I make it equal? I need 1440 rows...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.Grouper` for this:

```py
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='60min')).mean()
```

Comment: It works partly. After finding mean I want delete old data and keep mean value changing time interval to 60 secs

Comment: For this kind of thing it's useful to have some example data to play with. You could try adding some sample DataFrames via `df.head(20).to_dict()` or similar. It would also be helpful to see an example of the output you're looking for.

Comment: This code works fine, however i want to change time interval value to 60 secs. With this code it finds mean but time interval shows 4 secs

Comment: the code deleted my 'ch_name' column. How can I save that column?

Comment: Initial dataframe grouped by ch_name, so now it is grouping it by time, is there any other way to solve the question?

Comment: If time starts with 00:00:00 this dataframe has 1440 rows, but when time starts with 00:01:06 it has 1439 rows. How can I make it equal? I need 1440 rows...