# How to fill voids (Nan) in Dataframe with mean values of that column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 4 columns: ch_name, time, values, and interval. I want to check if "interval" < 300 secs check for NaN from "values" column. If there NAN values then fill NAN with mean of that column {'values'}.

```
[1798 rows x 2 columns]
                     value  interval
time                                
2019-09-26 00:02:00    0.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:03:00    0.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:04:00    0.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:05:00    0.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:06:00    0.0      60.0
...                    ...       ...
2019-09-27 05:55:00    0.0      60.0
2019-09-27 05:56:00    0.0      60.0
2019-09-27 05:57:00    0.0      60.0
2019-09-27 05:58:00    0.0      60.0
2019-09-27 05:59:00    0.0      60.0

[1798 rows x 2 columns]
                     value  interval
time                                
2019-09-26 00:02:00    1.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:03:00    1.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:04:00    1.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:05:00    1.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:06:00    1.0      60.0
...                    ...       ...
2019-09-27 05:55:00    1.0      60.0
2019-09-27 05:56:00    1.0      60.0
2019-09-27 05:57:00    1.0      60.0
2019-09-27 05:58:00    1.0      60.0
2019-09-27 05:59:00    1.0      60.0
```

Comment: Do you need `mean` of all values of `value` or mean of values only for `df['interval'] < 300` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solutions for filled maen of all values of column `value`:

```
mask = df['interval'] < 300
df.loc[mask, 'value'] = df.loc[mask, 'value'].fillna(df['value'].mean())
```

Or:

```
mask1 = (df['interval'] < 300) & df['value'].isna()
df.loc[mask1, 'value'] = df['value'].mean()
```

**Sample**:

```
print (df)
                     value  interval
time                                
2019-09-26 00:02:00    NaN      60.0
2019-09-26 00:03:00    NaN     400.0
2019-09-26 00:04:00    2.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:05:00    3.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:06:00   10.0     600.0


mask1 = (df['interval'] < 300) & df['value'].isna()
df.loc[mask1, 'value'] = df['value'].mean()

print (df)
                     value  interval
time                                
2019-09-26 00:02:00    5.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:03:00    NaN     400.0
2019-09-26 00:04:00    2.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:05:00    3.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:06:00   10.0     600.0
```

---

Solutions for filled means only by rows where `interval < 300`:

```
mask = df['interval'] < 300
df.loc[mask, 'value'] = df.loc[mask, 'value'].fillna(df.loc[mask, 'value'].mean())
```

Or:

```
mask1 = (df['interval'] < 300) & df['value'].isna()
df.loc[mask1, 'value'] = df.loc[(df['interval'] < 300), 'value'].mean()

print (df)
                     value  interval
time                                
2019-09-26 00:02:00    2.5      60.0
2019-09-26 00:03:00    NaN     400.0
2019-09-26 00:04:00    2.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:05:00    3.0      60.0
2019-09-26 00:06:00   10.0     600.0
```

Comment: Hey,mate. Can you help with this solution? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58163316/how-to-line-up-dataset-in-pandas/58163380?noredirect=1#comment102712214_58163380). This code works well however, I think it creates new dataframe. I need all initial columns. Thx

Answer (score 1):

you can use numpy solve this problem, take the column of data-frame you want to fill with mean value in your case df['interval']  check if there is empty of nan value's, it returns index where null, then replace with value you want, in your case 
 df[where_are_NaNs] = mean

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import *
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', ], ['juli', 14]]  #my empty cell in dataframe 
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 


where_are_NaNs = isnan(df['Age'])
df[where_are_NaNs] = 0.0
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Solution is wrong, because not replaced by condition.

Comment: @jezrael Can you help with above asked question please?